# Click on div, show a modal that has image and text (overwriting on a template) and work as slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, modal-dialog

I am trying to make this div class "box-1" to pop-up a modal when someone clicks on it. In the modal, there will be a header, an image, and some text will show up in the modal.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="grid_12">
            <h2 class=" wow fadeInUp" style="color: #000; font-weight: bold;">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <div class="row">
          <div class="grid_3">
            <div class="box-1 wow fadeInDown">
              <span class="skill-number" data-from="0" data-to="8" data-speed="0.5" ></span>
              <span class="skill-title">performance Awards </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid_3">
            <div class="box-1 wow fadeInDown">
              <span class="skill-number" data-from="0" data-to="8" data-speed="0.5" ></span>
              <span class="skill-title">performance Awards </span>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="grid_3">
            <div class="box-1 wow fadeInDown">
              <span class="skill-number" data-from="0" data-to="8" data-speed="0.5" ></span>
              <span class="skill-title">performance Awards </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

The codes I have tried works fine independently, but when I put it inside the template code, all the other code breaks if it works. I am trying to make the statistics section 'box-1' class div and 'service-box' div to work as a modal. [template link](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_51408/#services)

here are some of the links I have tried but did not work on the template. [jQuery pop-up overlay][2]